# Make inherited constraints stricter

Tags: grails, grails-constraints

In Grails when using `CommandObjects` or `DomainClass` how can I restrict a constraint of an inherited property?

Say I have a parent class with non-null property `payload`:

```
abstract class TextContentCommand extends ContentCommand {

    String payload

    static constraints = {            
        payload nullable: false
    }
```

In the subclass I'd like to make the property stricter and set the max length:

```
class FacebookTextContentCommand extends TextContentCommand {

    public static final int LENGTH_MAX = 4

    static constraints = {
        importFrom TextContentCommand
        payload maxSize: LENGTH_MAX
    }
}
```

This way is not working and when a longer string is provided the validation passes. My knowledge of Grails is very superficial. How can I restrict the inherited properties?

Answer (score 0):

The constant `LENGTH_MAX` was causing the problem. Providing the value directly makes the validation work again.

```
class FacebookTextContentCommand extends TextContentCommand {

    static constraints = {
        importFrom TextContentCommand
        payload maxSize: 4
    }
}
```